# VBA Sumif vs Sumifs

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

---

UPDATE:

Thank you for your help thus far! That definitely worked.

I am wondering though if there is a way to add a loop function as well. What i would like it to do is to reference Column A of Worksheet 888 to identify the same value in Column A of 999, and sum the values in the last column of the sheet (keeping in mind that the last column may differ, thus allowing the macro to be more dynamic).

```
Dim LastRow, LastColumn As Long 
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
LastColumn = Worksheets("888").Cells(1, 
Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 

For x= 1 To LastRow 
Cells(x, 2).Value = 
WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Worksheets("888").Range("A:LastRow"), 
Worksheets("999").Range("A:LastRow"), 
Worksheets("888").Range("LastColumn:LastColumn")) 

Next c
```

I keep getting the error "Unable to get the SumIf property of the worksheet function class. Any thoughts on how to fix?

Comment: Also, is SUMIFS a better option here? may add a bit more flexibility

Comment: see: https://exceljet.net/formula/3d-sumif-for-multiple-worksheets

Comment: Thanks Scott, very helpful. Is there a way that I could manipulate that formula into VBA as opposed to a macro? Additionally I am struggling to identify the correct criteria to include in the code; I originally input ("Sheet1").Cells("i:2") into the criteria segment of the SUMIF function, but I think i may have to reference a solitary cell or logical argument as opposed to a range of cells. Any thoughts there?

Comment: That definitely worked - I am wondering though if there is a way to add a loop function as well:

Dim LastRow, LastColumn As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = Worksheets("888").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For x= 1 To LastRow

    Cells(x, 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Worksheets("888").Range("A:LastRow"), Worksheets("999").Range("A:LastRow"), Worksheets("888").Range("LastColumn:LastColumn"))
        
Next c

I keep getting the error "Unable to get the SumIf propery of the worksheet function class. Any thoughts on how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

i don't really understand why do you want to use macro when formula can do the job

put below in C2 and drag down the formula should do the job

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!F:F,A2,Sheet2!H:H)+SUMIF(Sheet3!J:J,A2,Sheet3!L:L)
```

but if you insist macro,

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value = "=SUMIF(Sheet2!F:F,A2,Sheet2!H:H)+SUMIF(Sheet3!J:J,A2,Sheet3!L:L)"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C7").FillDown
```

Comment: That definitely worked - Thanks! I am wondering though if there is a way to add a loop function as well: 

Dim LastRow, LastColumn As Long 

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 LastColumn = Worksheets("888").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For x= 1 To LastRow 
Cells(x, 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Worksheets("888").Range("A:LastRow"), Worksheets("999").Range("A:LastRow"), Worksheets("888").Range("LastColumn:LastColumn"))
Next c 
I keep getting the error "Unable to get the SumIf propery of the worksheet function class. Any thoughts on how to fix?

Comment: try to amend your original post to add that code to make it more readable, but just by glance your issue is with "A:LastRow" "LastColumn:LastColumn" - they are variables so should not be in the semi-colan. remember last row/column is always in number not ABCDE